# Using Environment Variable in Play Application for a MAC system

Tags: java, macos, playframework, environment-variables

This article is what I am following to refer environment variables from my Java Play Application -
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using-environment-variables

In my application.conf file I have configured the value as -
`rabbitmq.hosts="rabbit.queue.service"` 
`rabbitmq.hosts=${?MQ_BROKER_HOSTS}`

I am testing it locally in my MAC and even though I have setup the environment variable for `MQ_BROKER_HOSTS` it is always picking up the default value which is `rabbit.queue.service`.

These are the things I have done to set `MQ_BROKER_HOSTS` as the environment variable in my local MAC -

Created a file **~/.profile** and added this line there: 
`export MQ_BROKER_HOSTS=localhost`

In the file **~/.bash_profile** added this line - 
`export MQ_BROKER_HOSTS=localhost`

Then I ran this command - 
`$ source ~/.profile` 
`$ source ~/.bash_profile`

After that I opened a new terminal and ran the command `env`, I can see the variable `MQ_BROKER_HOSTS` in the variable list.

I also run the command `printenv`, even their the variable `MQ_BROKER_HOSTS` is present in the list of variables.

I also tried `echo $MQ_BROKER_HOSTS` and it prints the output `localhost`.

Can anyone please let me know why my Play application is not able to pick the environment variable. Am I setting the environment variable correctly in my MAC or is there anything I am missing in my application.

In my play application, I am fetching the value as - 
`conf.getString("rabbitmq.hosts")` 
where conf is the instance of Play `Configuration` class.

I have already invested a lot of time in fixing this, any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks.